# How to select a shape in PowerPoint using VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint template where I need to select the shapes (both headings and body shape) between the black lines.

These shapes can change their top, left, height and width. I want to make it so flexible that even if I add any shape (like subtitle or conclusion) between these black lines, my code will select the above shapes **only** (both headings and body).

What I tried:

1. Using name or id, I selected these shapes but that will not fulfill my objective (to select a shape and create a copy), so creating a copy will still have a same name, which I don't want.
2. I defined range (top, left, height and width), but this is static. **Can I make it dynamic?**

Code for range selection -

```vb
Sub Add_Row_below()

    currentslide = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex
    
    'Selecting Only Shapes within a specified Range
    
    pTop = 78
    pLeft = 18
    pHeight = 370
    pWidth = 686
    Count = 0

    Dim slideShapes As Shapes
    Dim slideShape As Shape

    'Get shapes for the slide
    Set slideShapes = ActivePresentation.Slides(currentslide).Shapes

    'Remove any existing selection
    ActiveWindow.Selection.Unselect

    'Loop through the shapes
    For Each slideShape In slideShapes

        'Check if shape is within the specified boundary
        If ((slideShape.Top >= pTop And slideShape.Top <= (pTop +pHeight)) _
          And (slideShape.Left >= pLeft And slideShape.Left <= (pLeft + pWidth))) Then

            'Add the shape to the current selection
            slideShape.Select (msoFalse)
            Count = Count+ 1
                
            'Shrink text when overflow
            slideShape.TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape

        End If
    Next slideShape
    
End Sub
```

Template screenshot
[image]

Template created after a button click:
[image]

Template containing possible shapes (subtitles and conclusion) between the two lines:
[image]

Comment: When asking a question, it helps a lot if you use the same terms that are used in the program.Otherwise, we're guessing at what you refer to. I believe "headings" is the Title placeholder and "body" is the text or content placeholder. Top, Left, Width and Height are the position and size properties, not a range. You can check the Shape.Type, and for placeholders, the PlaceholderFormat.Type to help find the kinds of shapes you're after. Instead of using copy and paste, create a new placeholder that has the same size and type as the one you're trying to copy.

Comment: Thanks john for your feedback, i will be careful from next time.

Comment: Use ShapeIndex instead of ShapeName after duplicating the shape?
Or make a new shape with the same properties of the shape you would want a copy of?

Answer (score 0):

You could search for your lines by their **appearance:** line width, line weight (I guess `.left` would be the same)

You can use `shape.index`

Shape `index` is unique. Shape `Name` is not unique.

There should be two of them, so an error check could count and make sure you have your two lines. From there you can easily find anything which is below the upper line and above the lower line.

Comment: But any other shape can be added between those lines and i only have to select "headings"(Title placeholder) and "body" (text placeholder). Also, the indexes of shapes are random generated numbers, everytime i have to store that index as a record.

Comment: Indexes are always random. At least from your point of view ;-). But does it matter? You run your macro, it looks for lines (starting point far to the left, end point far to the right [if you don't have the exact values do some math like slide width minus 100 or so). Once you have your lines you can determine any other shape by its location (top/bottom). 
" i only have to select "headings"(Title placeholder) and "body" (text placeholder)" 
everytime i have to store that index as a record

I do not understand this part - sorry. Can you rephrase this please?

Comment: so, the objective is not to select those lines but to select headings and body. And when you say after knowing the dimensions of lines we can get the dimensions of headings and body, just need to understand how?(as any new shape can be added above headings and below body). I need to make it flexible enough that my required shapes are only selected and not the new shapes added above and below my headings and body respectively.

Comment: I feel pretty lost understanding the objective. Why can't you just insert a new shape with the same properties as the shape you would like to duplicate?

Comment: objective is, on a every button click duplicate the heading and body, now 3 headings and 3 body will be there in a row, and so on till 5 headings and 5 body shapes. The problem is, in order to duplicate, i have to select a shape(heading or body) but i don't have any identifier( index i can't use because with every new heading and body, i have a new index). I hope you got this bhavesh?

Comment: This is really difficult to understand -- So you want to have a button which creates new "heading/body" pairs and each time you apparently have to make the other ones smaller? With all the content in it? What is the content? Will there be pictures inside? Have you thought about using a smart art here? Something like horizontal bullet list  - but hard to say if we don't know more about your project. You might want to share some real life screenshots-

Comment: Why can't you just insert a new shape with the same properties as the shape you would like to duplicate? You wouldn't need to select any of your headings or body shape?

Comment: G.N. MS , yes you got me right, this how it will be done but lets assume the content inside the text box will only be text. I have attached the screenshots of how it will look after the button click. Also attached the Screenshot of a possible case where i can have any shape(here subtitle and conclusion is added) between those lines.

Comment: In this case it is best to identify the lines (which I described in my answer) and from there you can easily identify the other elements since they seem to be same width as Lines. Everything else would be Header/Body Pairs (and you can also identify them via their relations -- Header and Body share the same LEFT for example). I also would strongly advise to consider the question of @BhaveshShaha to CREATE a new shape. You also would have to do a lot of math to make sure the new pair is making the others smaller [(TotalWidth / n) - ((n-1)*spacebetween)]. complex project, Sir.

Comment: Bhavesh, yes i can do that but still in order to adjust the new shapes, i have to reduce the widths of previous shapes and that require selection of those shapes.

Comment: G.N. MS, yes i can consider your idea of finding relation between body and heading. Though i will give you some test cases like:  what if, when my subtitle shape , heading and body have same left. Also the height and width of heading and body can change. So there are actually N number of test cases possible. I know this is very complex thing to do. But i will think on the part of finding some other relations that you have suggested. Thanks, by the way!

Comment: Honestly, at this point, I feel like you can take the easy route out by just making 20 to 30 slidemasters :P

Comment: I really have difficulties to visualize your situation. Maybe if you can provide 5 or 10 possible REAL slides. But essentially the identification of the lines have to come first.- Maybe you follow @BhaveshShaha advice and create your slidemasters.